Google Chrome Mobile App triggers frame-src Content-Security-Policy
I have the following CSP for frame-src:
frame-src  'self' *.MYWEBSITE.it *.youtube-nocookie.com *.youtube.com *.google.com *.paypal.com *.braintreegateway.com *.braintree-api.com;

When i try to load a popup iframe of a pdf file:

It works fine on all Desktop Browser
It works fine on all Mobile Browser:
expect Google Chrome

Google Chrome Mobile triggers a Content-Security-Policy violation on directive "frame-src".
What could be the reason for that, does Google Chrome loads external plugins to display the PDF file ?

Yes, the built-in pdf viewer uses a hidden iframe, but it should be immune to CSP, so it must be a bug in mobile Chrome.

@wOxxOm  and idea for a workaround ? This issue seem to be present for many months.

Try reporting it in https://crbug.com, maybe they're unaware.
